# Getting even space around the centered dots in $1,\cdots,n$

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$1,\cdots,n$

\end{document}
```

There's more space to the right of the centered dots than to the left of them. What's the best way to get the space even?

(I think `$1,\dots,n$` looks better, but what if I really wanted centered dots and not low dots between the commas?)

Update: Okay, if I adapt LaRiFaRi's suggestion like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dotsc}{\DN@ {\ifx \@let@token ;\@cdots \,\else \ifx \@let@token .\@cdots \,\else \extra@ \@cdots \ifgtest@ \,\fi \fi \fi }\FN@ \next@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$1,\dots,n$

$1,\ldots,n$

$1,\cdots,n$

\end{document}
```

I can get `$1,\dots,n$` to look like what I have in mind---with the same space around the dots as in `$1,\ldots,n$`. Could a redefinition of `\cdots` be added to the above to make `$1,\cdots,n$` look the same as `$1,\dots,n$`? Just curious.

Comment: you're using `amsmath`.  the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`) covers this situation in section 4.3 (p.9).  there is a `\dotsc` if you want the default "dots with commas".  if you prefer `\cdots`, just add a thin space, `\,` before that command.

Comment: erh, where does one use `\cdots` with commas. The does should be on the line, not up in the air.

Comment: Simply use `\dots`; `amsmath` will choose the right form (on the baseline).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just enter a thin space, which is enough in this situation. Or you substract some space from the right part `\mkern-xxxmu`.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % for demo

\begin{document}    
    $1,\,\cdots,n$  
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As you notice, the common opinion is not to use a centred ellipsis here. I think that looks ugly and unknown, too. The preferred way would be to use the `\dotsc` command from `amsmath` here. If you still want to get it raised to the centre, you may create your own command. I just copied the definition of `\dotsc` without understanding too much of it. Sorry.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cdotsc}{\DN@ {\ifx \@let@token ;\@cdots \,\else \ifx \@let@token .\@cdots \,\else \extra@ \@cdots \ifgtest@ \,\fi \fi \fi }\FN@ \next@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $1,\cdotsc,n,\dotsc,n+1$ % or just \dots which will be interpreted as \dotsc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ellipsis dots between commas belong on the baseline, and nowhere else.

Comment: @Mico sure, but that was not the request.

Comment: Since a comma follows, `\dots` will make the right choice and use `\dotsc`. So `$1,\dots,n$` is the best way to go (provided `amsmath` is loaded, of course).

Comment: @egreg added that, but the OP already used that in his post and wanted to have a different thing. For whatever sake it would be needed...

Comment: Well, section 4.6 of the _Short Math Guide for LaTeX_ says, "For preferred placement of ellipsis dots (raised or on-line) in various contexts there is no general consensus," so I thought that if someone really thought centered dots between commas looked better than low dots, it might be nice to have a better, short way of getting them than simply typing `$1,\cdots,n$`.

Comment: @MSC And the opinion of many (including me) is that lshort is wrong in saying this.